# operator<< cannot output std::endl -- Fix?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, operator-overloading

The following code gives an error when it's supposed to output just `std::endl`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

struct MyStream {
  std::ostream* out_;
  MyStream(std::ostream* out) : out_(out) {}
  std::ostream& operator<<(const std::string& s) {
    (*out_) << s;
    return *out_;
  }
};

template<class OutputStream>
struct Foo {
  OutputStream* out_;
  Foo(OutputStream* out) : out_(out) {}
  void test() {
    (*out_) << "OK" << std::endl;
    (*out_) << std::endl; // ERROR     
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  MyStream out(&std::cout);
  Foo<MyStream> foo(&out);
  foo.test();
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The error is:

```
stream1.cpp:19: error: no match for 'operator<<' in '*((Foo<MyStream>*)this)->Foo<MyStream>::out_ << std::endl'
stream1.cpp:7: note: candidates are: std::ostream& MyStream::operator<<(const std::string&)
```

So it can output a string (see line above the error), but not just the `std::endl`, presumably because `std::endl` is not a string, but the `operator<<` definition asks for a string.

Templating the `operator<<` didn't help:

```
  template<class T>
  std::ostream& operator<<(const T& s) { ... }
```

How can I make the code work? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add this to your `struct MyStream`:

```
  std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& (*f)(std::ostream&) )
  {
      return f(*out_);
  }
```

`std::endl` is a function that appends a newline and flushes the underlying stream; this function signature accepts that function and applies it to the `ostream` member.

Then, as a test, defining `foo::test` as

```
  void test() {
    (*out_) << "start";
    (*out_) << std::endl;
    (*out_) << "done";
  }
```

will correctly output

```
start
done
```

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty crazy. How is one supposed to know that? There should be some class that one can derive from that would add such unsightly stuff automatically.

Comment: The thing to remember with overloading iostream operators is const char* and this function pointer. This is because the C++ template system has some special rules about pointer types. (They're ambiguous, I think?)

Comment: @dehmann: I have **no** idea how anyone was supposed to know that.  I had to try a few different Google searches to get *pointed* in the right direction, then I *still* had to piece the answer together.  Hopefully this helps a few more people in this situation.

Comment: It's not a function, but it's a function *template* (so that it's not specific to `ostream`, but also works for `wostream` and others). That's why a simple `T` doesn't work.